# System.IO.IOException: The specified server cannot perform the requested operation

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure-storage, symlink, windows-server-2012-r2

A bit of context:

- ASP.NET app running inside a VM (Windows Server-2012 and .NET Framework 4.6)
- It uploads files to a directory on the VM
- The directory is a symbolic link(virtual directory created from IIS I think) to a private Azure Storage
- It breaks sometimes when calling `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles($"*{fileName}*").FirstOrDefault()` after the files where uploaded

Behavior:

- It only happens sometimes, when reading multiple files one after
  another
- It worked great for a few years, until the summer 2019

Error:

```
 System.IO.IOException: The specified server cannot perform the requested operation. at 
    System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at 
    System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() at 
    System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) at 
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption) at 
    the method which uses the GetFiles() method showed before
```

Questions:

- Where could I start the investigation from?
- What are the usual suspects? I suppose the directory is not locked by
  another process because I saw that case has a more specific exception

Comment: Did you see anything wrong in system event? Besides, could you find a way to reproduce this issue all the time?   Did you see something wrong with process monitor? Since this is not a known issue, we may need to find more details. Of course, you could involve MS support to find the root cause.

Comment: @JokiesDing nothing seems wrong in system events or process monitor, so the app is working as normal. I suspect something happens between the app and the Azure Storage, through the virtual directory(we don't use the C# SDK)

Comment: You close it after reading files? or the same file that reading is not open in your VM?

Ensure that the file is not opened in any editor or IDE i.e. Notepad, Visual Studio etc.

Comment: @EffectlabCriaçãodeSistemas The file is not opened in any editor and the method calls are synchronous